# Expanding width of column in QTreeWidget dynamically

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside, qtreewidget

Using PySide, I am developing a small application. In my application, I am using QTreeWidget, to show form like data. This QTreeWidget has single column.My problem is that QTreeWidget not showing horizontal scroll bar when its element expands in horizontal direction. Has anybody have any idea about this issue?

After trying some things I noticed that I need to expand width of column dynamically. Is it possible?

Note:
I have tried 'setColumnWidth', it is working fine. But I want to do it dynamically.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, both is possible. Did you read Qt documentation?

Comment: @Dmitry thanx for taking interest. I tried but unfortunately I didn't get. Can you give me any link?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtreeview.html http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode

Comment: No success. Is it possible to you give example of pyside?

Answer (score 13):

You need to [resize to contents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum) as well as switching off [stretch last section](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop):

```
    treewidget.header().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    treewidget.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
```

Comment: treeview->header()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents); 

Works fine. Cool. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In PySide2 you can use this:

```
header = self.treeWidget.header()
header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
header.setStretchLastSection(False)
header.setSectionResizeMode(5, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```